# Blank Screen When Booting Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, amd-graphics

I have problems when booting Ubuntu 18.04 with kernel 4.15.0-36-generic, sometimes blank or can login but there are issues like this:

```
fbcon: amdgpudrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[drm:generic_reg_wait [amdgpu]] *ERROR* REG_WAIT timeout 1us * 100 tries - tgn10_lock line:566
WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 175 at /build/linux-39dmni/linux-4.15.0/drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu/../display/dc/dc_helper.c:190 generic_reg_wait+0xe8/0x120 [amdgpu]
Modules linked in: amdkfd amd_iommu_v2 amdgpu(+) chash i2c_algo_bit ttm drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops drm i2c_piix4 ahci r8169 mii libahci wmi video
CPU: 3 PID: 175 Comm: systemd-udevd Not tainted 4.15.0-36-generic #39-Ubuntu
Hardware name: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. MS-7A38/B350M BAZOOKA (MS-7A38), BIOS 1.F0 07/07/2018
RIP: 0010:generic_reg_wait+0xe8/0x120 [amdgpu]
```

please help me because this bug is very annoying, I have to force restart it, if it's blank when booting. I'm afraid my hardware is broken.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)